# Can't get S3 to trigger an SQS notification

Tags: go, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, localstack, aws-sdk-go

I can't seem to get S3 to trigger an SQS notification when using [aws-sdk-go-v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2) with [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack). I've appended the notification configuration to the local stack bucket in my configuration here:

```sh
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sqs create-queue --queue-name input-queue --region=us-east-1
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3api create-bucket --bucket input-bucket --region=us-east-1
cat >queue_notify.json <<EOF
{
  "QueueConfigurations": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "QueueArn": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:000000000000:input-queue",
      "Events": ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    }
  ]
}
EOF
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3api put-bucket-notification-configuration --bucket input-bucket --notification-configuration file://queue_notify.json
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sqs list-queues --region=us-east-1
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 ls
```

My method here puts a gzipped object into S3.

```golang
func UploadToS3(cfg aws.Config, bucketName string, objectName string, content string) error {
    var buff bytes.Buffer
    var err error
    gz := gzip.NewWriter(&buff)

    _, err = gz.Write([]byte(content))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err = gz.Flush(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err = gz.Close(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    input := &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: &bucketName,
        Key:    &objectName,
        Body:   bytes.NewReader(buff.Bytes()),
    }

    client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg, func(o *s3.Options) {
        o.UsePathStyle = true
    })

    _, err = client.PutObject(context.TODO(), input)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

But, when I invoke this method no SQS notification seems to get triggered. Even though the object was added to the bucket.

```golang
conf, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(
            context.TODO(),
            config.WithRegion("us-east-1"),
            config.WithEndpointResolver(
                aws.EndpointResolverFunc(func(service, region string) (aws.Endpoint, error) {
                    return aws.Endpoint{
                        PartitionID:   "freid",
                        URL:           "http://localhost:4566",
                        SigningRegion: "us-east-1",
                    }, nil
                }),
            ),
        )

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

bucket := "input-bucket"
object := "integration/sample.log.gz"
content := "Hello World!\n"

err = UploadToS3(conf, bucket, object, content)
```

I've checked the SQS queue via the AWS cli and there is nothing in it:

```json
{
    "Attributes": {
        "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible": "0",
        "VisibilityTimeout": "30",
        "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed": "0",
        "MaximumMessageSize": "262144",
        "CreatedTimestamp": "1613393896.119463",
        "ApproximateNumberOfMessages": "0",
        "ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds": "0",
        "DelaySeconds": "0",
        "MessageRetentionPeriod": "345600",
        "LastModifiedTimestamp": "1613393896.119463",
        "QueueArn": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:000000000000:input-queue"
    }
}
```

Oddly, I can verify that a SQS notification is triggered when manually uploading a file to the local stack S3 bucket using the AWS cli:

```sh
aws --endpoint http://localhost:4566 s3 cp ./examples/sample.log.gz s3://input-bucket/integration/sample.log.gz`
```

Here, I can see that there is one message waiting:

```json
{
    "Attributes": {
        "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible": "0",
        "VisibilityTimeout": "30",
        "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed": "0",
        "MaximumMessageSize": "262144",
        "CreatedTimestamp": "1613393896.119463",
        "ApproximateNumberOfMessages": "1",
        "ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds": "0",
        "DelaySeconds": "0",
        "MessageRetentionPeriod": "345600",
        "LastModifiedTimestamp": "1613393896.119463",
        "QueueArn": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:000000000000:input-queue"
    }
}
```

Why does this notification not get triggered when I upload a file using golang? Do I need to add something to my bucket configuration when using golang? And, if so what?

Comment: AFAIK, in order for an S3 bucket to automatically put notification about an uploaded blob to a linked SQS, this has to be explicitly configured, so this is an AWS confiuration issue and has nothing to do with Go (you could have use any sort of client to upload to the S3 bucket). (I mean, we're using this scheme at my $dayjob: a provider uploads its stuff to a bucket we own, and the bucket notifies the SQS queue linked to it. We do not even know which software the provider uses to put their stuff to the bucket.)

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking its a config issue too. I'm just not sure where. For example `s3:ObjectCreated:*` should encompasses the `PUT` operation. For my use case most of the time it will be another client actually uploading to this bucket. I just want to test the functionality at the component level and hence need to put the blob to local stack.